# How to assign corresponding author in BioMed template?

Tags: templates, authorindex, email

I am using BioMed Template. I have two authors and I want to assign the second author as corresponding author. However, it does not work. Could you help me to solve it?

The online link at

https://www.sharelatex.com/project/578396a00050c8630b1d2ec9

This is template .cls file

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% AUTHOR
% if corref is not set, we will use first author with an email as a corresponding author
% \corr@author@id -> {au1}
% \corref@list    -> {aff1,aff2}

\newif\ifauthorcorref@notset \authorcorref@notsetfalse


\def\bmc@author{\@ifnextchar[{\author@fmt}{\author@fmt[]}}

\def\author@fmt[#1]#2{%
  \stepcounter{author}{%
  \csname author@cmd\endcsname%
  \author@correffalse%
  \xdef\author@id{au\the\c@author}%
  \setkeys{author}{#1}%
     \@ifundefined{num@author}{\@tempcnta=10\relax}{\@tempcnta=\num@author\relax}%
     \def\a@sep{, }%
     \ifnum\@tempcnta>1\relax%
       \ifnum\c@author=\@tempcnta% 
          \let\a@sep\authorand@sep%
        \else% 
          \let\a@sep\author@sep%
        \fi%
     \fi%
%
  \ifauthorcorref@notset%
    \ifauthor@email% email is set
       \author@correftrue%
       \global\authorcorref@notsetfalse%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  \ifauthor@corref%
     \xdef\corr@author@id{\author@id}%
     \@ifundefined{corref@list}%
       {\@ifundefined{current@address@list}{}{\xdef\corref@list{\current@address@list}}}%
       {}%
  \fi%
%
```

Answer (score 2):

The link you provided shows an example in which the second author is the corresponding author. Just make sure your corref is inside the correct \author[].

```
\author[
 addressref={aff1}, 
 email={jane.e.doe@cambridge.co.uk} 
 ]{\inits{JE}\fnm{Jane E} \snm{Doe}}

\author[
 addressref={aff1,aff2}, 
 corref={aff1}, % This is the command that designates corresponding author  
 email={john.RS.Smith@cambridge.co.uk}  
 ]{\inits{JRS}\fnm{John RS} \snm{Smith}}
```

Comment: For some reason it did not work for me, but only worked when I had more than a single affiliation for more than 1 author when they all shared the same affiliation, so I just duplicated it leaving it redundant